# Show div on selecting name from array

Tags: html

I have a div hidden initially, a text box which performs a live search in the database and returns an array of the matched results. I want to make the div visible only if a value from the array is selected and hide it otherwise. How can i do this?

```
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="b.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>  

<script>

function showDiv() {

$("#panel").slideDown("slow");
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>ESAMP</h2>
<h3 class="sup">SUPPORT</h3>    
<h3 class="fed">FEEDBACK</h3>
<div class="container">
<div class="tag"><p>SEARCH</p></div>    
<input class="box" type="text" name="serch" id="serch" placeholder="Enter Your Software Name" onEnter="showDiv()"/>
<input class="mybutton" type = "submit" value="Search"  onclick="showDiv()">    
 </form>


<img class =resize src="texture_graphite_blue.jpg" alt=""  />
<div id="panel"  style="display:none;" class="panel" > 
HELLO
</div>
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

currently i am showing the div on a button click. I want to show the div when the input value is selected from an array.

Comment: Show your code, then it's easier to help you.

Comment: How does the selecting from the array happen? through another div?

Comment: I have added my code. The array is returned from an autocomplete function using jsp.